# Insert function's return into another function's parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, return-value

I'm creating class and have to modify all of parameters while passing into external library functions. For ex:

```
myFunc(x, y, width, height) {
   someFunc(x * zoom.x, y * zoom.y);
   anotherFunc(x * zoom.x, y * zoom.y, width * zoom.x, height * zoom.y);
}
```

To do this more simple I try to find a method for passing this arguments way easier, like creating function:

```
minimize(x, y) {
   return [x * zoom.x, y * zoom.y];
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
myFunc(x, y, width, height) {
   someFunc(minimize(x, y));
   anotherFunc(minimize(x, y), minimize(width, height));
}
```

That is the minimize function will return "x * zoom.x, y * zoom.y" for place it in arguments of other function. I wonder if it can be done in this or similar way

UPDATE: Since Javascript now has spread operator, it can be done just as

```
myFunc(x, y, width, height) {
   someFunc(...minimize(x, y));
   anotherFunc(...minimize(x, y), ...minimize(width, height));
}
```

Comment: "I wonder if it can be done in this or similar way": have you actually tried? What were the results? The best way to find out is by doing.

Comment: I tried creating minimize return by array and object only, I just haven't got any other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I guess you're looking for `apply`:

```js
someFunc = function(x, y) {
  document.write("in someFunc: " + [x,y] + "<br>");
}

anotherFunc = function(x, y, width, height) {
  document.write("in someFunc: " + [x,y,width,height] + "<br>");
}
  
minimize = function(x, y) {
  return [x * 100, y * 200];
}

myFunc = function(x, y, width, height) {
   someFunc.apply(this, minimize(x, y));
   anotherFunc.apply(this, minimize(x, y).concat(minimize(width, height)));
}

myFunc(3, 4, 5, 6)
```

The last call is not particularly elegant, to make it look like in your example, we'd need a helper function:

```
Function.prototype.applyConc = function(thisArg) {
    return this.apply(thisArg, [].concat.apply([], arguments).slice(1))
}
```

and then:

```
anotherFunc.applyConc(this, minimize(x, y), minimize(width, height));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result of one function to a variable, and then pass this variable in as an argument to your other function.

```
var args = minimize(x,y);
someFunc(args);
```

Hope this helps